# Castle Windsor resolve an object with parameters

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

```
public class Component1
{
    public Component1(Component2 comp, Component3 comp3)
    {
        Component2 = comp;
        Component3 = comp3;
    }

    public Component3 Component3 { get; set; }

    public Component2 Component2 { get; set; }
}

public class Component3
{
    public Component3(Component2 comp)
    {
        Component2 = comp;
    }

    public Component2 Component2 { get; set; }
}

public class Component2
{
    private Guid _guid = Guid.NewGuid();
}

[TestMethod]
    public void InjectingUsingDictionary()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For<Component1>().ImplementedBy<Component1>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<Component2>().ImplementedBy<Component2>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<Component3>().ImplementedBy<Component3>().LifestyleTransient());
        Component1 c;
        var component2 = new Component2();
        using (container.BeginScope())
        {
            IDictionary arguments = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "comp", component2 }, { "Component2", component2 } };
            c = container.Resolve<Component1>(arguments);
            c.Component2.Should().Be(c.Component3.Component2);
        }
    }
```

Hi to all!
When I Resolve I want pass an instance of Component2 to initialize all props and Windsor passes it to all constructor parameters in the whole object graph. Is it possible?

Comment: Not by default. BY default this behaviour is disabled as it implies the used of the root component must have intimate knowledge about its entire graph, and it leads to problems

Comment: Ok. How should I do next task:

Comment: I have IService which has DoJob(). This IService uses some other services. All services logs their work using ILog. My clients call IService.DoJob and they need logs. So I wanted create instance of ILog and after that create instance of IService which logs all events just for one call of DoJob.



I have a solution:

1) Make Component2 Life style scoped.
2) Register factory method for it in the container.
3) 
using(container.BeginScope())
{
var service = container.Resolve<IService>();
Service.DoJob();
var log = service.Log;
//using log results
}